# Implement appointment slot booking with payment option

Tags: magento2

I'm trying to implement an appointment slot booking system where people can simply pay and start chatting/calling with a professional. What I mean is that on a particular page there would be a list of professionals(for example lawyers) with some descriptive information about them. Customers could then verify themselves with email or a mobile OTP system and then pay for a slot through a payment gateway.
I understand that it is a huge ask and not actually truly a Magento use case but my client's website is already built on Magento. I understand that building this sub-platform on a web-based framework such as Laravel and then integrating with the website would make more sense but I want to check if anything on Magento would allow me to achieve the same.
A close example of what I'm trying to achieve: https://www.apollo247.com/specialties/dermatology
Thank you so much for any and all help!

Answer (score 1):

It's a really and don't so hard to implement on Magento end and make sense to do if you already has everything built on Magento.
I think best one option is implement custom product type based on virtual product with related entity such a professional with prices, schedule, etc.

Alternative is have each professional as Virtual Product with own properties. You can manage all professionals as product, show them with some categories and order service.

You can restrict to pay (checkout) your product type in cart for guests and require additional verification before or simplify checkout flow with other rules.

You can do and control everything on each step